# Removing trailing zero's from decimal

Tags: php, decimal

Hi i was wondering how i could remove the last 2 zero's as seen below:

```
13.6500
16.0000
17.5345
```

To the following:

```
13.65
16.00
17.5345
```

Comment: use `round($input,2)` to round to two decimals

Comment: `number_format($number, 2);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`round()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) like this to round to 2 decimal points like this

```
echo round("13.6500",2);
```

Also you can use [`number_format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) like this

```
echo number_format("13.6500", 2);
```

Both yeilds the O/P

```
13.65
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ecf9216ac59c30b1efdce333fc65d1cca752dd33)

**EDIT**

from the comment i think what you want is like this

```
$input = "12.00000";

$length = strlen(substr(strrchr($input, "."), 1));

if($length > 2)
{
    $input =$input+0;
    if(strlen(substr(strrchr($input, "."), 1)) < 1)
    {
        $input = $input.".00";
    }
    else if(strlen(substr(strrchr($input, "."), 1)) < 2)
    {
         $input = $input.".0";
    }
    echo $input;
}
else
{
    echo $input;
}
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae4ac42ea0aaa1ceb855f14b3a575083c5f34da0)

Comment: Thanks for your response but i forgot to mention that it shouldnt round the decimal incase there are more then 4.

Comment: @user3600204 can you give examples ?

Comment: @user3600204 how `17.5345` remains the same ?

Comment: 17.5345 should remain the same but if there are zero's after the first 2 decimals they should be removed. Also the edited part doesnt seem to work :(

Comment: @user3600204, I got you.I think now i got what you want.Check my edit answer and tell was this you was looking for ?